# remove default jqgrid edit form and replace with custom dialog form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I need to show custom edit form from jqGrid edit click(default edit button) and need to avoid default edit jqGrid edit window.

I have provided below options for navGrid

```
$("#EmpGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#EmpGridPager',
{ /* parameters */
  edit:true, add:false, del:true, searchtext:'Find&nbsp;', refreshtext:'Refresh&nbsp;' 
},
```

Comment: Have you had any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't posted enough details about your requirements. Nevertheless you have two main options which you can use: you can either use `editfunc` parameter of `navGrid` (you need define it on the same level as `edit: true`) or you can use `edit:false` alternatively and use `navButtonAdd` method to add custom button which looks exactly like Edit button. If you use the first alternative you need just know that the first parameter of `editfunc` callback is the rowid of selected row. If you use the alternative way then you need use `.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selrow") to get the id of selected row`. In both cases you can use `getRowData` or `getLocalRow` to get information about editing row.